# How to Stop Reading Input After a Certain Character?

Tags: python, arrays, list, input, counter

I'm meant to stop reading an input after a "!" appears. This is part of my code:

```
msg = input("What is your message? ")

print()

lett = 0
otherch = 0
num_vowels = 0
num_consanants = 0

count_character = [0] * 100000

for character in msg.upper():
    if character == "!":
        print("lett =", lett)
        print("other char = ", otherch)
        print("num_vowels = ", num_vowels)
        print("num_consanants = ", num_consanants)
    elif character < "A" or character > "Z":
        otherch = otherch + 1
        count_character[ord(character)] = count_character[ord(character)] + 1
    else:
        lett = lett + 1
        count_character[ord(character)] = count_character[ord(character)] + 1
for character in msg.upper():
        print("character", character, "appeared" , count_character[ord(character)] , "times")
```

However, if i run the program and input something such as "hello!hi" it continues to read the text after the exclamation point and goes on to say that there are two H's and one I in the input.
Any helpers?

Comment: you have to break your loop when you encounter the !

Comment: just a piece of advice - you're posting many little questions pertaining to bugs in the same homework program. While SO can be really helpful, I've found that debugging and digging through the docs is the best way to learn programming. You'll get a lot better if you examine your code line by line and figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `break` inside the `if character == "!":` block. It jumps out of the `for character in msg.upper():` loop.